# python writing byte-by-byte to serial port didn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, pyserial

As discussed before in the forum reading problem is being solved but now getting write problem. I want to write some hexadecimal address to the serial port. the address looks like:

```
    000062240
    000062A4B
    000062244
    000062245
    000062D50
    00006225E
    00006A25F
```

I want to write them byte by byte with the delay of 0.01 sec. To write I do:
Before writing I need to write N and that works perfectly. After C I need to write the address. I put the inner loop in the text file to read the address. But `ser.write(line[line1-1])` give the string can not combine with int error. Any solution?

```
for line1 in range(1,8):
                  ser.write(line[line1-1])
                  time.sleep(0.01)
```

The writing code :

```
with open('lut.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
             #print line
             ser.write('N')
             time.sleep(0.01)
             ser.write(' ')
             time.sleep(0.01)
             ser.write('C')
             time.sleep(0.01)
             for line1 in range(1,8):
              ser.write(line[line1-1])
              time.sleep(0.01)
              line+=1
              time.sleep(0.01)
```

For the reference complete code.

```
import serial, time
from addresstable import *
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 38400
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS 
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE 
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE              
ser.xonxoff = False    
ser.rtscts = False    
ser.dsrdtr = False  
number_address = 10
number_char = 9  
timeout=1
#f=open('lut.txt','r')

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
         ser.flushInput()
     ser.flushOutput()
# reading        
         max_packet = 20
         lines = 0
         while True:
           byteData = ser.read_until('\r',max_packet)
       newdata=str(byteData)
           print newdata.strip()

       ser.write('I')
           time.sleep(0.01)
# writing
           with open('lut.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
             #print line
             ser.write('N')
             time.sleep(0.01)
             ser.write(' ')
             time.sleep(0.01)
             ser.write('C')
             time.sleep(0.01)
             for line1 in range(1,8):
              ser.write(line[line1-1])
              time.sleep(0.01)
              line+=1
              time.sleep(0.01)



    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing now:

for line in f:

```
     ser.write('N')
     time.sleep(0.01)
     ser.write(' ')
     time.sleep(0.01)
     ser.write('C')
     time.sleep(0.01)
     #for line1 in range(1,8):
     line="line"+"0"
     print len(line)
     requ = binascii.unhexlify(line)
     for i in requ:
      ser.write(i)
      time.sleep(0.01)
    line+=1
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with much simpler way. For future reference.

```
for i in line:
              newdata=i
              ser.write(newdata)
              time.sleep(0.01)
```